# xcode 7.1 for iOS 9 missing libc++.dylib required for Objective C Realm Static Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, ios9.1

I am following this doc for integrating realm in my iOS app.

[Realm static framework for iOS](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#getting-started)

My problem is in step 3. I am unable to find libc++.dylib. I find a few other .tbd ones but none of them are libc++.

I followed a few other SO posts on using the "add other" option and doing command+shift+G and find that library but it's not in that list either.

Does anyone know any workarounds?

Comment: same problem for me, the application crashes on the first Realm-related command with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Same issue, but upgrading an older cocos2d-x project to a new version of cocos2d-x framework. I think your question applies.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. I found some kind of way around.

1. Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
3. From /usr/lib you can add : libc++.dylib and more...
   Compile and have fun

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue in the Xcode 7 beta.

To work around this issue for now, please:
Delete all references to *.tbd* files from either your linked libraries phase, or from the copied bundle resources phase (where they sometimes will be added).
Add the library you want to link manually to the `"Other Linker Flags"` build settings, by adding the argument:
             `-l<library_name>`
          for each library you want to link (for example, add "`-lsqlite3`" (without quotes)).

For those who are curious, the .tbd files are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK, and help to significantly reduce its download size.

-- copy from [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4572)

finally, you can add `-lc++` in this `Other link Flags` setting

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem. I cannot find libc++.dylib through xcode but I found it using terminal.

You can copy or create a link to visible folder in xcode like /Users//Downloads.

Command below maybe help to fix the problem.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libc++.dylib /Users/<your user>/Downloads/libc++.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Realm the other week after the iOS 9 update. I know you already tried the method of going to build phases, add other, CMD + shift + G without success. However this was the method I used to locate libc++.dylib and I just checked it out again now and was able find it.

It is also worth mentioning that after you do manage to add libc++.dylib you may have build errors. In which case the fix I used was to go into your target's build settings and change Enable Bitcode to No.